# malformed Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
contents="""<tag>
</tag><t>text</t>"""

shorted= re.sub(r'(?s)<tag>.*?</tag>[^\w\s]*', '', contents).replace('\n', '')
print(shorted)
print()
```

result:

```
t>text</t>
```

Expecting "`<t>text</t>`" but the first "`<`" of "`<t>`" is missing, why?

Comment: Because `<` matches with `[^\w\s]`. What did you intend to do with `[^\w\s]*`?

Comment: If you're trying to remove content between tags, change it to `(?s)<tag>.*?</tag>[^<]*` or `(?s)<tag>.*?</tag>[^<\w\s]*` for non-word, non space, non-tag content.

Comment: Why regex for this pur XML. There are good parsers like xml.entree.ElementTree at python available, what can solve your question too.

Comment: Not every tag in text needs a full blown xxl parser.

Comment: @trincot "Because < matches with [^\w\s]" yes,  now I realize it...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a xml parser for xml processing, but anyway if you prefere `re`, try `re.compile()` and `findall()`:

```
import re
contents="""<tag>
</tag><t>text</t>"""

pattern = re.compile("<t>.*")
out = re.findall(pattern, contents)
print(out[0])
```

Output:

```
<t>text</t>
```

Comment: @Herman12 nice one!